# How to send an array to a method from specific location

Tags: java, arrays

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
    if(args.length>2){ print(args.getArrayFromIndex(2)); }
    else { print(args); }
  }

  public static void print(String... list){
    for(String str : list){ System.out.println(str); }
  }
```

I want to know if there is some build-in method for that or the only option is to create new array from index 2 and sent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 6 or later you can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method that takes the original array, the initial index (inclusive), and the last index (exclusive), and returns a copy of the specified range:

```
if(args.length>2){
    print(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 2, args.length));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how isn't it `args.length-1`? The `to` argument isn't included, weird.

Comment: @nir Correct, the doc says the `to` is not included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to copy array from index to another index.

Comment: dasblinkenlight beat u to it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you *really* do not want to create a new array, you can modify your `print()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    if(args.length>2){ print(0,1,args); }
    else { print(0, args.length-1,args); }
  }

  //start and end are inclusive
  public static void print(int start, int end, String... list){
    for(int i=start; i< end+1 ; i++){ 
       System.out.println(list[i]); }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about resources spent on creating new array instance, try this:

```
public static void print(int startFrom, String... list){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by `Java.util` like this

```
if(args.length>2){ 
{
   String[] partOfArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 2, args.length - 1);
   print(partOfArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about overloading `print` method to also use range value?

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] arr = { "0", "1", "2", "3" };
    if (arr.length > 2) {
        print(2, arr);
    } else {
        print(arr);
    }
}

public static void print(int start, String... list) {
    for (int i = start; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}

public static void print(String... list) {
    print(0, list);
}
```